Where does the inequality $f(x)\geq (x-11)^2$ comes from?
I'm trying to follow the answer to this problem on Lang's first course in calculus:



Part of the solution is:





Question: Where does the inequality $f(x)\geq (x-11)^2$ comes from?
I'm thinking about if for a bit of time but nothing useful comes up to me.

Since squares of real numbers are always nonnegative,
$$
f(x) = (x-11)^2 + (x^3-3x-1)^2 \ge (x-11)^2 + 0.
$$

Jesus Christ, I'm so stupid. I was making the calculations via Mathematica and was seeing only the expanded polynomial. Thank you so much!

We don't need to be stupid people to have “stupid” oversights :)
